# Check if the element is range then compare it to another range

Tags: vb.net, numbers, compare, range

Range number is Element in Ports array. Which is 1000-2000. 
For this element, I want to compare if this range's each element contains elements 1500-1600. If yes then wrong and If no then it's okay.

This is the problem I am solving. Currently, I am not sure how can I detect if the element is a range as *-* and each element from it to another range of ports and handle comparing.

Have tried to match it with "-" to detect if the current array element is range and then proceed for some code. But its not working.

```
for each item in ports
if the item = regex.ismatch([anynumber]-[anynumber]) then Listbox.items.add(item)
next

for each item in listbox
if item.range.contains(another range) then "NOTOK" else "OK"

next
```

Output should be if list of ports contains 5555 and used ports range is given as 5000-5600 then it should show error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was big problem but as I proceeded with arraylist and listbox this is solved. tp is arraylist of ports plus the range of ports. listbox14 are the ports range we need to compare with items 10-80,

```
For Each item In ListBox14.Items
    Dim cooler() As Char = item
    For i As Integer = range(0) To range(1)
    ListBox15.Items.Add(i)
    Next
else 
ListBox15.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

So now listbox contains all the range items I need to compare! 
TP is ports collection,
    For Each item In tp
                If ListBox15.Items.Contains(item) Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Wrong PORT" & item
    Else 
    Listbox7.items.add("True")
    End IF

```
IF listbox7.items.count = tp.count then TextBox1.Text = "ALL PORT are good to GO" & item
```

This really worked for me while I looked into it more and more! 
Thanks to all StackOverflow threads for generating this idea and completing this research.

Comment: Are you using the ListBox to store information or for an actual visual control to the user?

Comment: No they are just there to record compare and check if a certain range's number is in that numbers list or not. I took a range 4000 to 5000 I added all of them to numbers in listbox. Then compared to another listbox of used ports.

List box can be used outside of forms in other forms plus outside of loops too. Which makes them better instead of arrays or arraylist.

Comment: If they aren't used for visual then you should use list or array and make them public, they'll be available for all forms.